# Why is Docker for Windows running slow on WSL2?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, wsl-2

I was trying to get a Laravel image up and running on Docker for Windows (Windows 11), and after config, it was taking several seconds to load each page (insanely slow, definitely outside Laravel benchmarks). I am using WSL2 and have native (full resources) allocated to the VM. Why is it running so slow?

I inspected resource allocation and it shouldn't be a problem (50% memory and all cores). I have a fairly beefy machine. I tried a reinstall and new Docker image and closed all competing tasks.

Comment: Is your docker running inside your WSL? I had similar problem and I used `docker-for-windows` or `docker-desktop` which set up its own variation of WSL and that ran properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: don't host docker files on the WSL mount. Either use non-WSL docker or do an SSH deployment to the WSL local filesystem.

The issue ended up being that my project files were loaded under /mnt/c in WSL, and, for some reason, this is VERY inefficient for file access and modification. I ended up moving my files to a local folder in the VM (for me, this was my home folder) and page loads reduced to sub-second. Just the move (mv x->y) took a few minutes and my fans were going crazy.

Comment: WSL2 and Windows behave as though they are in the same network but not on the same machine. /mnt/C is a mounted network drive and those tend to be much slower than native local drives. As far as I know WSL(1) behaved differently though

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. It was an insane difference in speed. Also worth noting that it broke Vite as well.

Comment: @apokryfos I edited the question to reduce scope to WSL2.

Comment: Yes, this is documented here https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/